# setting recorded macro to be a dynamic code

Tags: vba, excel

I have recorded this macro. It's for inserting a chart. How can I create a chart shape and a sign it to a variable for later reference? I want to pass a variable to the range. I just want to change the (52) number. So if the variable is `row` how can I use it in the following code. I tried this

```
("'Simpson'!$K$3:$L$row")
```

But it doesn't work

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Simpson'!$K$3:$L$52")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "integrated function chart"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleHorizontal)
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "x values"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5""""").Activate
'How can I delete the legend in one. combining the next two
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried this and it ("'Simpson'!$K$3:$L$row") doesnt work

Try this

```
Dim LRow as Long

LRow = 52 '<~~ Change this as required.

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Simpson'!$K$3:$L$" & LRow)
```

Comment: I think that would work but how can assign the new chart to a variable and refer all the changes we want to applly to that variable.
will this work `chart = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=xlXYScatterSmooth, _
    Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200`

Comment: Do you mean creating a chart from the scratch and update those values on the go?

Comment: yep but I will use the one I created. I will just update the range. I tried your method and it does work. thank you.